# Jquery toggle password visibility only partly working

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have an interface with multiple options/requests to enter a password. I am trying to create one Jquery function to toggle the password visibility for all of them without using specific selectors. My function shows the password on the first click but didn't hide it on the second click. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$('#toggle_pw_vis').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').find('input[type=password]').attr('type', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'text' : 'password');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After first click, your type of input changed from password to text 
And when you click second time, script trying to find the input type password `.find('input[type=password]')` that doesn't exist after first click

So, for my opinion it would be good to add a class to the password input (`.password-input` for example), and work with that
should look something like that

```
$('#toggle_pw_vis').click(function () {
    $('.password-input').attr('type', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'text' : 'password');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea why I didn't realize this. Problem solved.